# Trying to shutdown computer remotely in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, shutdown

Helps master's, here is my coded when i try to shutdown remotely

```
  Process.Start("shutdown", "-s -m \\COMPUTER NAME")
```

Then when i executed the program nothing happens..
I think my coded is not correct or i am missing something.

Comment: http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/form/Shutdown%20Utility.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shutdown command can fail for a number of reasons but you're not checking for success. Try this instead and then lookup the error.

```
    Dim proc = Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /m \\COMPUTER_NAME")
    proc.WaitForExit()
    If proc.ExitCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox("Failed - Code = " & proc.ExitCode)
    Else
        MsgBox("Success")
    End If
```

Note: you may need to run your application as an elevated process.

---

Before testing your application you should test that the command works from the command prompt.

- Open `cmd`
- Run `shutdown /s /m \\COMPUTER_NAME`
- Check the output and make sure it worked. I suspect you'll get an access denied error. If so the right click on `cmd` and choose `Launch as administrator`. Then repeat this and make sure it works.
- If this doesn't work then your program wont either. Google `shutdown access denied` and work through some of the trouble shooting tips.

Comment: What a nice little snippet, I have never thought of checking the `ExitCode` property!

Comment: thanks for the code and now the exit code that i get is "5" and I don't know what it means thanks for your help

Comment: now the exit code that i get is "5" means access denied.. my problem now is how to remove the access denied so that i can remotely shutdown pc's

Comment: Start with making sure you can run that exact shutdown command from the command line. Then make sure you're running your application as the same user. If the command line needed an elevated prompt then you'll need to elevate your process too.

Comment: now i'm confused on how to do it.. and i have no idea

Comment: yup i still get access denied even if i run it as an administrator ..but thanks for your help..